# ImportError: No module named elementtree.ElementTree

Tags: python, import

I am running python 2.7 and am picking up a project from a different developer so I just trying to get it to compile and was getting import errors because the old developer was using  "import elementtree.ElementTree as ET" so I am going around and replacing that code with "import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET"

But now ran into this file that still wont compile. Here is the Traceback:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Time clock\source\TimeClock>python timeclock.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timeclock.py", line 30, in <module>
    from CheckHoursDialog import CheckHoursDialog
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Time clock\source\TimeClock\CheckHoursDi
alog.py", line 11, in <module>
    from StudentEarningReport import StudentEarningReport
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Time clock\source\TimeClock\StudentEarni
ngReport.py", line 10, in <module>
    import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
ImportError: No module named elementtree.ElementTree
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is the first 40 lines of the file.

```
"""StudentEarningReportPanel

Panel to show what students earned, based on the StudentEarningReport.
"""
__history__ = """History:
3/18/2010: Added ShowXML button
"""
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled


from datetime import datetime as DT
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET



from PyCollapsiblePane import PyCollapsiblePane as PCP
#~ try:
    #~ from agw import pycollapsiblepane as PCP
#~ except ImportError: # if it's not there locally, try the wxPython lib.
    #~ import wx.lib.agw.pycollapsiblepane as PCP

CP = PCP.PyCollapsiblePane



class ReportPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    """ReportPanel(parent, node)
    Parent is the wx.Window-based parent.
    Node is an ElementTree.Element created by StudentEarningReport.py
    """
    def OnPaneChanged(self, evt=None):
        self.SetupScrolling(scrollToTop=False)

    def __init__(self, parent, node):
        assert ET.iselement(node)
        #~ ET.dump(node)
        self.Elem = node
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you pasted is the same code you're trying to run? When I run into this, it's usually because I forgot to hit `^X^S`/`cmd-S`/whatever in the editor… (But also check that there is no `StudentEarningReport.pyc` file that somehow has a newer timestamp than `StudentEarningReport.py`.)

Comment: Actually… this looks like a file that's probably called `StudentEarningReportPanel.py`, while the error is in `StudentEarningReport.py`. Could that be the problem? (Another dumb mistake I make all the time.)

Comment: FYI, python does not "compile"

Comment: YES! thank you it was a silly mistake on my part. You suggestion helped me look for the simpler error. There is another file in the source that has almost the same name and exactly the same imports and I was editing it instead!

Bingo yeah! there was a StudentEarningReportPanel.py. You guys are awesome Thank a bunch! its always a the layer 1 problems with the simplest solutions that take the most time to trouble shoot!

Comment: @Dhara: Actually, it _does_ compile. That doesn't mean the same thing most people are expecting it to mean, but it's still true.

Comment: @abarnert As you point out, not in the sense most people are expecting it to mean

Comment: @Dhara: And yes, he is getting a runtime error while executing the `import` statement in a successfully-compiled file, not a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've fixed `StudentEarningReportPanel.py`, but you're importing `StudentEarningReport.py`, which you haven't yet fixed.